# Compare two dates using Momentjs

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to compare two dates. I want to check and see if one date is before another. I'm using momentjs and everything I do seems to return `false`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Format - [Month, Year]
moment([0, 2012]).isBefore([1, 2013]);
```

Comment: according to documentation since both dates are invalid it will return false

Comment: The documentation has `moment([2012, 0, 31])` I've just dropped the day. How would I write it correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will always give you an invalid date the way you have coded it. There are many ways to construct the date using moment. Try this:

```
var a = moment([2012, 0]);
var b = moment([2013, 1]);
console.log(a.isBefore(b)); //returns true
```

On the same note, please read the docs carefully on the usage of "0" as the month, before and after version 2.1.0:

Months are zero indexed, so January is month 0.

> Before version 2.1.0, if a moment changed months and the new month did not have enough days to keep the current day of month, it would overflow to the next month.

```
// before 2.1.0
moment([2012, 0, 31]).month(1).format("YYYY-MM-DD"); // 2012-03-02
```

> As of version 2.1.0, this was changed to be clamped to the end of the target month.

`// after 2.1.0
moment([2012, 0, 31]).month(1).format("YYYY-MM-DD"); // 2012-02-29`

Comment: Hey @Joey thanks for putting up the detail. I assume this is a more concise way of coding what I put up as an answer?

Comment: Yes, an alternative to drop the day referring to your original question. I don't think there is any major performance difference if that is what you were wondering.

Comment: and what if i want to compare two dates @JoeyEzekiel ?

Answer (score 0):

What seems to work is this:

```
var a = moment({month: 0, year: 2012});
var b = moment({month: 2, year: 2014});

console.log(a.isBefore(b))
```